# Return value from object array where a certain requirment is met

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, filter

In my template I have products, which have an image. You can order these products which needs to make the image a different image. An order can have multiple statusses being Order placed, Ordered and Received. I need to get the status from the product with a certain Id. This is my template:

```
<div *ngFor="let lproduct of locationProducts">
      <div class="productDivWidth" *ngIf="lproduct.departmentId.departmentId == location.departmentId.departmentId">
        {{lproduct.productId.productName}}
        <br>
        <img *ngIf="IsOrdered(lproduct.productId.productId) === null" src="{{lproduct.productId.productImage}}"
          class="product-image">
        <img *ngIf="IsOrdered(lproduct.productId.productId) === Openstaand"
          src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/175/175461.svg" class="product-image">
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
          (click)="OrderProduct(lproduct.productDepartmentId)"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My function:

```
 IsOrdered(id: number) {
    return this.orders.filter(e => e.productId.productId === id).statusId.statusName;
  }
```

Comment: I edited your post to use the block code formating and make it clearer to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter method returns an array so try to replace it with find which returns first matching item as I suppose ID's are unique so change your return statment to

```
return this.orders.find(e => e.productId.productId === id).statusId.statusName
```

Comment: It is a good practice to check for null before accessing the property after find method